# pygame know when I am in the X range and Y range

Tags: pygame, transformation

I was making a game and now I want to see how could pygame know that I am in x of player and y of player.

I have to break in safe, to do that I must stand where it is and stay there for 3 seconds.

problem is even that I managed to alert pygame that I am in area where safe is,
is how could pygame know that I am in safe for 3 sec.

This is non-optimal:

```
import time
now = time.time()
future = now + 3
while future > now:
    #IT DOESNT WORK WELL IN WHILE LOOP TO ALERT YA,
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: It "doesn't work well" is not very clear. What is it about your solution that does not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: As written above, How could i see if x and y of my PLAYER is x y of BOX

Comment: That simply reiterates your code doesn't meet your requirements. It doesn't say _how_ it doesn't work for you, specifically. i.e., does it sort of work, but not quite meet your requirements? What is the _nature_ of the failure. Being able to describe your problem clearly is key when solving your own problems.

Comment: safe (x,y)
player (x,y)
if player in safe:
    do things

Comment: Assuming you want to have some player object be safe when it is in a specific location, but only for a few seconds, you probably want to research "events". My guess is you already know how to detect when an object is within a given location you have defined. Once you detect this, then you could raise an event that is fired some seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to "alert" pygame/your code is you could use `if` statements if your using non-OOP and all you have is a list of coordinates for your player location, or if you do have an object for your player you could `pygame.sprite.Sprite` as a super class. Here's the solution if your using a coordinate list and not a big class.

```
loc = [x, y]  # Don't run this because it won't understand what x and y are. This is just an example
safe_rect = ( x , y , w , h ) # Using tuple because I assume that the safe doesn't move

while True:
    if loc[0] >= safe_rect[0] and   # The newlines are for readability
       loc[0] < safe_rect[0] + safe_rect[2] and
       loc[1] >= safe_rect[1] and
       loc[1] < safe_rect[1] + safe_rect[3]:
        not_yet_existent_do_something_function()  # Performs statements once inside the safe
```

If you want to include a timer, do this:

```
import time
loc = [x, y]
safe_rect = ( x , y , w , h   )
# Time variables
time = time.time()
time_wanted = time + 3  # 3 seconds after the time is assigned to time

while True:
    if loc[0] >= safe_rect[0] and 
       loc[0] < safe_rect[0] + safe_rect[2] and
       loc[1] >= safe_rect[1] and
       loc[1] < safe_rect[1] + safe_rect[3]:
        if time.time() > time_wanted:
            not_yet_existent_do_something_function()
```

I hope this works for you, if you have a question about what I did please ask me.